The logic of LSZ, counterterms and field strength renormalization
I'm reading Coleman's lecture notes on Quantum Field Theory(World Scientific Press).
Coleman first showed that[Chapter 13, equation (13.2)], in a theory with an adiabatically turned on&off interaction and counterterms. That is $H = H_0 + f(t; \Delta, T) H_I$, where $f(t)$ is an adiabatic function. Counterterms are needed to ensure conditions such as $\left<0|S|0\right>$(Chap 9 & 10). The scattering amplitude in the theory can be written as:
$$
\left<k_3, k_4 | S - 1 | k_1, k_2\right> = \prod_{r = 1}^{4} (-i)(k_r^2 - \mu^2) \tilde{G}^{(4)}(-k_3, -k_4, k_1, k_2)
$$
where $\tilde{G}^{(4)}(-k_3, -k_4, k_1, k_2)$ is the sum of all Feynman diagram with four external lines' propagator included. In this theory, there is no field redefinition.
Then the LSZ reduction is proved:
$$
\left<k_3, k_4 | S - 1 | k_1, k_2\right> = \prod_{r = 1}^{4} (-i)(k_r^2 - \mu^2) \tilde{G}^{'(4)}(-k_3, -k_4, k_1, k_2)
$$
where $\tilde{G}^{'(4)}(-k_3, -k_4, k_1, k_2)$ is the Fourier transform of the 4-point renormalized Green function in the physical theory($H = H_0 + H_I$, without adiabatic function)
$$
G^{'(4)}(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \left<0|T(\phi'(x_1)\phi'(x_2)\phi'(x_3)\phi'(x_4)|0\right>
$$
and $\phi'$ is the renormalized field s.t. $\left<0|\phi'(x)|0\right> = 0$ and $\left<k|\phi'(x)|0\right> = e^{ikx}$.
I'm a little confused about these two equations, since they are both right. Can someone point out the difference between these two equations and the underlying logic behind LSZ reduction.
